# Is there any framework / program to control Android emulator via Code?

Tags: android, e2e-testing, root-access

I know this probably is not for stackoverflow.

I'm looking for a framework or program that lets me control an android emulator with code.
Imagine Selenium or Puppeteer but for android.

Use cases:

Open applications, scroll page, use selectors to find elements in hierachy and click on them, click on input, enter text etc

What I found so far is UI Automator, appium, but I don't quite understand what is what since I'm completely new to Android's ecosystem.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: if you are wanting to do this with your own app, it's built into the dev environment as "testing".  You can write scripts to send touches, click specific buttons, etc.
if not, it is technically possible but due to cross-app security, it's definitely not easy.  We licensed a testing suite and they  had to install a service on the device.

Comment: @JohnLord Thank you for the reply, It's safe to say I know nothing about Android in this regard, as you mentioned there is some "cross-app" security, is there any known tool to bypass this? would a rooted version of android help?